# Where to ask question about extracting data from optical media?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have several hundreds of optical media disks (mainly DVD-R & CD-R) that stores data, that needs to be transferred to a hard disk drive to improve accessibility.

I need to ask a question about how to make a strategy (software/hardware system) to optimise the time used to perform extraction of this data from all of the disks.

In which community should this type of question be raised?

Sample question:

> I need a good strategy for extracting data from several hundreds of optical media disks to a filesystem.
>
> The process of extracting should be as easy as inserting the media into a drive, get extracted, then automatically ejected when finished. Alternatively, inserting several media disks into a media carrousel, inserted the carrousel into the "drive", and give feedback when it is finished extracting all of the disks, either by playing a sound or sending an e-mail.
>
> Are there any solutions already available, and if not; What hardware and what software / operating system would I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is effectively a hardware and software recommendation question, your best bet is on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) and [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Since the technical part is the most important in my opinion (if you buy a carousel, it probably tells you what OS you need, etc), I would try to see if it is on-topic on Hardware Recommendations.

Read their [help center](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or ask on their meta before posting your question!

Comment: I will try to ask on HR meta first if this is the right community to ask this type of questions. Thanks.